# When was the first ecocide “committed”?

Tags: meaning, etymology, semantics

Dictionary.com defines ***[ecocide](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ecocide)*** as an Americanism dating back to 1965–70:

> the destruction of large areas of the natural environment by such activity as nuclear warfare, overexploitation of resources, or dumping of harmful chemicals.

Other sources suggest that its earliest  usages date to  1969 [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ecocide) or 1970 [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecocide) for instance.

While Google Books offers a few earlier usage instances such as:

from [Official Records of the ... Session of the General Assembly](https://books.google.it/books?id=asFPAQAAMAAJ&q=%22ecocide%22&dq=%22ecocide%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjauaSElp_kAhWIK1AKHW7mD_A4ChDoAQg1MAM)[5](https://google) (1947):

> One delegation said that while disturbance of ecosystems could be tolerated to some extent, beyond a certain limit it ***could lead to ecocide***. The need for redeployment of industry in the interests of more efficient and less waste- producing ...

When and where was the term ecocide coined? Has its meaning changed through the decades given the greater and greater attention ecological issues  have attracted in recent years?

Comment: Are you sure that the report is from 1947? While that is the original publication date for Official Records, Issues 24-26 may be 24-26 years after this (assuming annual publication), putting it at 1971-1973. I ask this because I thought I'd found an earlier publication through Google Books, and was fooled by the same thing - in my case, The Progressive started in 1929, but the excerpt was from an issue in the early 1970s. Google Books is notoriously tricky with indexing periodicals properly.

Comment: Are you asking when It was first commited? Or when the word was coined?  It may very well have been done long before there was a name for It.

Comment: Uh, Noah's flood?

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin - it could be a false positive,  but I couldn’t confirm it.

Comment: More likely from the 1973 document: https://books.google.com/books?id=LVQ9AAAAYAAJ&q="ecocide"&dq="ecocide"&hl=en than 1947

Comment: Firstly, it's a hyperbole. You don't call killing a part of something *-cide*. Technically, *ecocide* would leave nothing left of the environment but its ashes. The term is used for emphasis and effect. In the other sense of "killer of" as in *herbicide*, it's just a convenient usage. Furthermore, the prefix ***eco-*** is attested from **1969** (https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=eco-) so *ecocide* could not have been anywhere around before that date.

Comment: @Kris The prefix *eco-* has been around for longer than 1969. Even in your link, *ecosystem* and *ecosphere* are respectively from 1935 and 1953. The OED posits that specialist usages were around early in the 20th century, with more general usage in the 1960s with the environmental movement. Finally, dictionaries may represent early instances of usage found by a specific team of lexicographers, but it's often possible to use corpuses and archives to find even earlier usages. So I would seldom declare that, just because "Etymonline" or the "OED" say a date, the word didn't appear earlier.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin (and two others): Look more closely. The usage of *eco-* in the contextual sense did not appear until the late 60s. It's not the same as in *ecology* and related terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ecocide** is one of several words formed from the prefix *eco-*, which generated words in English after *ecology* came into wider usage. According to the OED, many of these words were formed in the early 20th century, and *ecocide* has usage cited from 1969 (Oxford English Dictionary, [eco-, comb. form](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/59377)):

> 1969   Encycl. Sci. Suppl. (Grolier) 159   Discarded automobiles, old newspapers and telephone books, tin cans, nonreturnable bottles—all add to the growing problems of solid-waste disposal... **Ecocide**—the murder of the environment—is everybody's business.

This date corresponds to the Merriam-Webster date. To see if I can find anything further, I'm using two databases. Indications from these results is that (a) *ecocide* referred to a pesticide in the 1960s, and (b) gained its more general environmental usage by 1970.

**JSTOR** - Egler, Frank E. Ecology, vol. 47, no. 6, 1966, pp. 1077–1084. JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/1935663.

> Further sound thoughts on this general subject are voiced by Roland C. Clement in a talk on "Mosquito control and wildlife," April 20, 1966, to the Northeastern Conference on Mosquito Suppression and Wildlife Management, at Newton, Mass. In the equally problematic field of vertebrate pest control, Alfred G. Etter's "Testimony of an ex-federal trapper" (De- fenders of Wildlife, July, 1965) reveals one of the most vigorous one-strand specialists in our society, the Sheep- man, together with the branches of our government that he has intimidated, as the subject relates to the **ecocide** 1080.

"Ecocide 1080"? I thought it was a numbering error at first, but [according to Norbert Finzsch](https://books.google.com/books?id=lXt_DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT82&lpg=PT82&dq=%22ecocide%201080%22&source=bl&ots=C7_SRI_xpu&sig=ACfU3U1p6BQq8p3uwHCIjhhA9hdaABLqCA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjs9vLLnp_kAhWOiOAKHf11A2YQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22ecocide%201080%22&f=false) (2018) this is one name for a pesticide used in the early 1960s:

> A substance with the scientific name *sodium fluoracetate*, that was used as rodent killer in the US and as 'dingo bait' in Australia, was called 'ecocide 1080.'

Finzsch cites 1080 as the origin of *ecocide*; the chemical is well-documented ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_fluoroacetate)). JSTOR turns up one more citation before 1970, also authored by Frank Egler, where he again refers to "ecocide 1080  (sodium fluoracetate)" : Egler, Frank E. American Scientist, vol. 56, no. 4, 1968, pp. 484A–486A. JSTOR, www.jstor.org/stable/27828398.

**New York Times** archive - "And a Plea to Ban 'Ecocide'." New York Times (1923-Current file), Feb 26, 1970, pp. 38.

> Taking his cue from the Convention on Genocide, a Yale biologist has proposed a new international agreement to ban "**Ecocide**" - the willful destruction of the environment. Prof. Arthur Galston, director of the Division of Biological Sciences at Yale, made the suggestion last week at a conference in Washington on War and National Responsibility. In doing so, he pointed with alarm to United States defoliation and crop-destroying practices in South Vietnam, where he said there is evidence of "irreversible damage" to plant life.

This is the most commonly cited origin of the term in academic articles I've found. Even in 1970, the New York Times treats this as a new usage (using quotes reserved for nonce words and new words), indicating that they may have been unaware of the academic use to refer to the pesticide 1080 in the previous decade. On the other hand, given that Galston was a biologist and seemed to work in ecology, it seems likely he was aware of Frank Egler or other ecologists using *ecocide* to refer to pesticides. Galston's addition was to use the term more generally to refer to ecological destruction, rather than to the mere destruction of a single species by a product.

Note: One open question is how, according to the OED, an Encyclopedia Science Supplement from 1969 could have a definition that Galston uses in 1970. If anyone has access to a vintage book collection, maybe they could confirm the citation and actual publication date.

Comment: See my comment at OP.